# Chinese Translation With Sentences Including 像。。。一样，各种各样，。。。以上

Tags: translation

I had these sentences I needed to translate.

I was wondering if anyone could check if they were correct or not.

Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: can work for us = 可以為我們工作 (會 = would)

Comment: 1) 在暑假期間, .....  & 5) as addressed by Tang Ho. Otherwise, well done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I don't see any problem for the first four translations, but for the last one, you used `會` to translate 'can', which is problematic: while English does not make the distinction between **ability** and **permission** when using 'can', Chinese does.
2. When you say `會`, as in `我會游泳` (I can swim), you are indicating **ability** (I am able to swim).
3. When you say `可/可以`, as in `你可以在這裡游泳` (You can swim here), you are indicating **permission** (You are permitted to swim here). The fifth sentence is such a case. Being over 18 years old is a prerequisite in obtaining the permission to work here. So better say `十八歲以上的人可（以）為我們工作`. Using `會` for ability does not make sense.